# Laravel 4.2 : Session is destroyed when redirecting

Tags: php, redirect, session-cookies, laravel-4.2

When user is logged in, the browser normally redirecting to dashboard page. But, instead of showing the page, the browser shows white page with plain text "Redirecting to : http://.......com/dashboard" and back to login page. I've checked log files in storage/logs/laravel.log, but found nothing.

- Everything works fine on local development (I use XAMPP to develop).
- Source code is uploaded to hostgator

Any ideas why this happen? I've read so many articles about this, but this weird behavior still exist
Thanks !

```
public function doLogin() {
    //validation rule
    $rules = [
        'username' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required'
    ];

    $messages = [
        'required' => ':attribute is required.'
    ];

    $credentials = [
        'username' => Input::get('username'),
        'password' => Input::get('password')
    ];
    $validator = Validator::make($credentials, $rules, $messages);
    if ($validator->passes()) {
        if (Auth::attempt(['UserID' => Input::get('username'), 'password' => Input::get('password'), 'Status' => User::ACTIVE])) {
            if(checkMatrixCategory('dashboard')){
              return Redirect::intended('dashboard');
            }
            return Redirect::intended('profile');
        } else {
            return Redirect::back()->withInput(Input::except('password'))->with('error', 'Wrong username/password.');
        }
    }
    return Redirect::back()
                    ->withErrors($validator)
                    ->withInput(Input::except('password'));
}
```

My route :

```
Route::get('/', array('as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'UserController@showLogin'));
Route::post('/login', array('as' => 'user/login', 'uses' => 'UserController@doLogin'));
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function() {
    Route::get('/profile', array('as' => 'profile', 'uses' => 'HomeController@showProfile'));
    Route::post('/profile', array('as' => 'profile', 'uses' => 'HomeController@doUpdateProfile'));
    Route::group(array('before' => 'matrix'), function() {
        Route::get('/dashboard', array('as' => 'dashboard', 'uses' => 'HomeController@showDashboard'));
```

filters.php :

```
Route::filter('auth', function() {
  if(Auth::guest()) {
    if(Request::ajax()) {
      return Response::make('Unauthorized', 401);
    } else {
      return Redirect::guest('/');
    }
  }
});

Route::filter('matrix', function() {
  $route = explode('/', Route::getCurrentRoute()->getPath())[0];
  if(!checkMatrix($route)) {
    Auth::logout();
    return Redirect::route('home')->with('accessDenied','Access denied! Please call your administrator to get permissions.');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem long ago. After searching couple of days I found There is a problem with laravel  generateSessionId **function when it comes to 4.2 version**  . 
you can check if there is a **multiple session files generate** during redirection . Then this is  the only reason .
you can find this method here **projectFOlder/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Store.php.**. line :171

```
protected function generateSessionId()
    {
//      return sha1(uniqid('', true).str_random(25).microtime(true));
            return md5('Getpikk');
    }
```

this is what i did to solve my problem . I hope it helps you too..